# (UWP) mediaElement causing error:unsupport video type or invalid file path

Tags: c#, xaml, video, uwp

I've try to play video on a page upon loaded by using mediaElement

here is the XAML code

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" Width="400" />
    </Grid>
```

and here is a C# code

```
public async void initVideo()
        {
            mediaElement.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/sampleVideo.mp4");
            mediaElement.Play();
        }
```

The video I want to play resides in Assets folder. However when the page is loaded it gives Error:Unsupported Video type or Invalid file path

I've try with mp4 , flv, wmv file so it's unlikely that this is caused by unsupported video type

I've follow this example too https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187272.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

but it's also causing same problem

Is there any error on my path? how to solved this?   thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone that try to help!! but I've found what goes wrong myself

At first I've copy my .mp4 file and paste to the Assets folder directly by file explorer. This case got an error

But when I copy my .mp4 file and paste in the Assets folder through Visual Studio it correctly can find a correct path now and playing the video correctly

Answer (score 0):

mp4 is supported on UWP platform. So your problem is 'invalid file path'.

In your code, the uri is 'ms-appx:///Assets/sampleVideo.mp4', so your mp4 file should be in 'Assets' folder in 'Solution Explorer' and the '**Build Action**' of mp4 file should be '**Content**'.

So please check your file path and 'Build Action'.